# How to execute a script every 1st Saturday and 3rd Saturday of a month

Tags: cron

I have a requirement to execute a script every 1st Saturday and 3rd Saturday at 8.30 AM. I am new to using the cron job in Linux. Please let me know if the following will work.

```
30 8 1-7,14-20 * * [ `date +\%u` = 6 ] && /path/to/myscript
```

Taking into consideration

- First Saturday falls between 1 - 7
- Third Saturday falls between 14 - 20

The cron job should run on every one of those days and immediately exit if it's not Saturday.

Please advise.

Comment: Your approach is sound I think but perhaps the second range should be 15-21? (If the month starts on Sunday, the first Saturday would be the 7th and the 14th would be the **2nd** Saturday). Also `=` should more correctly be `-eq` (integer rather than string equality)

Comment: @steeldriver You should post that as answer

Comment: I would start the script every saturday and check inside the script  and exit if it is not the 1st or 3rd.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689834/6030 = Use Dillon Crontab version.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably simplify this down to:

```
30 8 1-7,14-20 * 6 /bin/bash /path/to/script
```

[As per Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#30_8_1-7,14-20_*_6), this will run At 08:30 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and every day-of-month from 14 through 20 and on Saturday.

Comment: Thanks. May be a dumb question . What does the /bin/bash do in this job?

Comment: Generally one runs a cron job as `root` to ensure the task is performed regardless of whether you’re logged in or not. As a result, you need to specify where `bash` is located in order to run the script. `/bin/bash` is the full path to the program.

Comment: @matigo I think the OP wants logical AND here (only on Saturdays that fall within 1-7,14-20). Your recipe will run on all days of the week between 1-7,14-20 *as well as* all Saturdays regardless of where they fall in the month, no?

Comment: ... also why `/bin/bash`? we don't even know that `/path/to/myscript` is a bash script - it could be zsh or csh or python or ... . In any case, AFAIK both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in the default cron `PATH`

Comment: Agree with @steeldriver, this will run every day between 1-7 and 14-20 and all Saturdays. crontab.guru actually confirms this if you click on the ["next" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7UGi.png) above the input.

Comment: It should be `30 8 1-7,15-21 * 6`, as the third week is 14 days after the first week.

Comment: Hi All thanks, How about this 30 8 1-7,14-20 * * [ `date +\%u` = 6 ] && /path/to/myscript

Answer (score 0):

instead of 14-20 it should be 18-24 because 14 -20 will not satisfy the 3rd Saturday of every month condition